# Sort Array in numerical order based on a numerical value within the element

Tags: php, arrays

How do you sort an array in numerical order, based on a numerical value within the element: where the element is a String?

for eg. from:

```
Array(
0 => One:3 
1 => Two:1
2 => Three:4
3 => Four:2
)
```

to:

```
Array(
    0 => Two:1
    1 => Four:2
    2 => One:3
    3 => Three:4
    )
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your input array:

```
$arr = array('One:3','Two:1','Three:4','Four:2');
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
  return filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) - filter_var($b, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
});
print_r($arr);
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Two:1
    [1] => Four:2
    [2] => One:3
    [3] => Three:4
)
```

Comment: this one works! what about if the values were decimal? I used FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT instead of FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT for the decimals but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: `filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION)` The third parameter is needed to allow `.` to be filtered

Answer (score 0):

If your string follow this pattern you can use the [uasort()](http://php.net/uasort) function and build a function that sorts it. Example:

```
$elements = array('One:3','Two:1','Three:4','Four:2');

uasort($elements, function($a, $b){
    $a = array_pop(explode(':', $a));
    $b = array_pop(explode(':', $b));

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
});

print_r($elements); // Array ( [1] => Two:1 [3] => Four:2 [0] => One:3 [2] => Three:4 )
```

Comment: Your output indexes are out of order. Does that matter?

Comment: I tought I saw the keys out of order on the expected result when I first looked at the question, that's why I used uasort :)